# How to correctly add safe area inset to UIStackView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I have a simple stack view with two text inside it and I have added safe area constraints,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello, World!"
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let label2 = UILabel()
    label2.text = "Hello, World!"
    label2.sizeToFit()
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label2)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
  }
}
```

But it has big amount of space between two text. How do I remove that space? This only happens when I add this line `stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)`.

[image]

Comment: Try to give bottom constraint >= ```stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)```

Comment: @RajaKishan That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: What is the stack view for? Just position your labels directly.

Comment: @matt I am using stack view to position. Positioning directly is a pain as I am gonna have to add constraints for each label as far as I understand.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the StackView's making it so the elements in it are filling up the space equally.
Try setting: stackView.distribution = .fill
Here's an article about how StackView works and why that's happening to you: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/22/uistackview-distribution/

Comment: This wont make a difference since it will just move the labels towards the bottom. The first label will be positioned in the middle of the screen and the second label in the bottom